# Proof to show an expression equals $e^{-x\cos(\frac{2\pi}{\alpha}))}\sin(x\sin(\frac{2\pi}{\alpha}))$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I need to prove

> $$\frac{e^{(-1)^{\frac{2}{\alpha}}x}-e^{-(-1)^{\frac{2}{\alpha}}x}}{2i}=e^{-x\cos(\frac{2\pi}{\alpha}))}\sin(x\sin(\frac{2\pi}{\alpha}))$$

**My attempt:**

we can write $$e^{(-1)^{\frac{2}{\alpha}}x}=\exp\{x\cos(\frac{2\pi}{\alpha})+ix\sin(\frac{2\pi}{\alpha})\}$$

Using this I can get $$\frac{\exp\{x\cos(\frac{2\pi}{\alpha})\}\exp\{ix\sin(\frac{2\pi}{\alpha})\}-\exp\{-x\cos(\frac{2\pi}{\alpha})\}\exp\{-ix\sin(\frac{2\pi}{\alpha})\}}{2i}$$ but this expression is not equal to the right side of my first equation. Am I doing something terribly wrong? BTW the expression on the right side of my first equation is from an IEEE transactions paper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not correct. Try $\alpha=2$ to get

$$\frac{e^{-x}-e^x}{2i}=e^x\sin(x.0)=0$$

Comment: so this means my expression is correct but the expression in that paper is wrong.

Comment: Yes, indeed $(-1)^{\frac{2}{a}}=(e^{i\pi})^{\frac{2}{a}}=\cos(\frac{2\pi x}{a})+i\sin(\frac{2\pi x}{a})$. However, when calculating the numerator one cannot factor the cosine-exponential term out since minus is not inside $\cos()$, which is the actual mistake in the RHS. They have different signs.

Comment: thank you for your help. I was thinking that I am missing something.